# Parse a Path from Java program

Tags: java, parsing, zip, bufferedreader, readfile

Have a file on specified path `/foo/file-a.txt` and that file contains a path of another file

`file-a.txt` contains: `/bar/file-b.txt` this path at line one. need to parse the path of `file-b.txt` and zip that file and move that zipped file to another path `/too/` from my Java code.

I been till the below code then i m stuck.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Reader 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try 
    {

        String CurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/foo/file-a.txt"));

        while ((CurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(CurrentLine);
        }

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        try
        {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

am getting path as text, help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Help with what? What do you expect us to do? Write this for you? You are already doing IO, just search on how to do IO with zip files.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis didnt mean to Write code for me, i m just expecting the suggestion for how do i parse that specified file for Path, i am getting the path as text, so

Comment: Use `new File(pathAsString)` to convert to `File` object??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the actual *zipping* of the file, [this](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/adding-files-existing-jar-file) page may be of help. 
As a general note, this code will replace the current existing zip file.

```
public class TestZip02 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      zip(new File("TextFiles.zip"), new File("sample.txt"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void zip(File zip, File file) throws IOException {
    ZipOutputStream zos = null;
    try {
      String name = file.getName();
      zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zip));

  ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(name);
  zos.putNextEntry(entry);

  FileInputStream fis = null;
  try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = fis.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) {
      zos.write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    zos.flush();
  } finally {
    try {
      fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
  zos.closeEntry();

  zos.flush();
} finally {
  try {
    zos.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
}
```

}
}

For *moving* the file, you can use `File.renameTo`, [here's an example.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-move-file-to-another-directory-in-java/) 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. i got solution.